# transfert data from sheet to sheet based on Column Value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i don't have a high skills on coding, but im' trying to transfert data based on a column value. i made my code that it's making most of what i wabt but still the last part of my code is to transfert based on value of a cell for example cell number 4.
ths is my code that i'm using
thanks you in advance

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15nIAXcP0a14OvvBr5lww4tO23stQD4PEu0QDAcgaFyE/edit#gid=0";
var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var pasteSheet = ss2.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

 // get source range
var max = copySheet.getMaxRows().toString();
var range = copySheet.getRange(2,1,max,4);
var source = range.getValues();

var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,max,4).setValues(source);
range.clearContent();

// get destination range
var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,max,1);

// clear source values 
Browser.msgBox('Commande Confirmer');
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're saying about cell number 4.  Are you trying to use cell number 4 as an input for the copying of the sheet?  I mean like a parameter to control the actual copy range?

Comment: the cell number 4 will contain the value that will based on it the transfert of the values to the 2nd sheet

Answer (score 0):

#### Try something like this:

```
function lfunko() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var url = "";
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var psh = ss2.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  const vs = csh.getRange(2, 1, csh.getLastRow() - 1, 4).getValues();
  let a = [];
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (r[33]) {
      a.push((r));
    }
  });
  if (a & a.length > 0) {
    psh.getRange(psh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, a.length, a[0].length).setValues(a);
  }
}
```